# wrap based on attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I'm trying to modify some dblatex XSLT code that processes docbook documents into LaTeX.  We've done quite a few mods for our local needs, but this one has me stumped.

There's an 'audience' attribute that can appear on virtually any docbook XML element.  In our docs, most elements are unmarked for this attr, but some are marked either 'tech' or 'nontech', e.g.

```
<chapter audience='tech'>
  (lot of stuff)
</chapter>
```

Rather than using the "profiling" mechanism, I would like to wrap the LaTeX code that results from processing the  elements that have such an attribute, with a LaTeX tag, i.e.

```
\technical{ \chapter (lots of stuff) }
```

My attempt at xslt code for doing this wrapping looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match=".[@audience='tech']">
    <xsl:text>\technical{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, the result of this is that the XML element that matched this template doesn't get processed, only its daughters do (as would be expected when there's no @select attribute on the xslt code).  So if the original was

```
<chapter role='tech'>
   <section>blah blah</section>
</chapter>
```

then the LaTeX output has the LaTeX code for the section, but not for the chapter.

Contrariwise, if I change the above xslt code so it has an explicit

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
```

then I get an infinite recursion.

Conceptually, what I want to do is to tell xslt to process an XML element that has the @audience attr by outputting the LaTeX wrapper \technical{...}, then process the same element while ignoring the @audience='tech' attribute.

Is there a way to do this?  I'm using xslt v1 elsewhere, although I guess if it's necessary to use xslt v2, I could make the change (not sure how that's done, but there must be a way...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `mode` attribute, available since XSLT 1.0.
Modes make it possible to differentiate between templates that match the same nodes, but perform different actions. Hence, the same elements can be processed multiple times. More information can be found [in the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="firstRun"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter[@audience='tech']" mode="firstRun">
        <xsl:text>\technical{</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="secondRun"/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter" mode="secondRun">
        <xsl:text>\chapter{</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Would that require me to specify a mode on all the elements that are allowed by the schema to have the @audience attr?  Which I certainly wouldn't want to do (there are 100s of elements in docbook, and the dblatex code is already complicated enough). Guess I'll have to try it and see if I can omit the "secondRun" above.

Comment: You can omit the `secondRun` mode, I only included it to illustrate the mechanism. In general, if an `xsl:apply-templates` element specifies a mode, then it only applies the templates of that mode. Otherwise, it applies the templates that do not belong to any mode (i.e. the default behaviour). Conversely, a template that specifies a mode can only be matched by a `xsl:apply-templates` of the same mode.

Comment: @Mike Maxwell, was this answer sufficient, or do you need further assistance?

Comment: I was going through all the questions I had asked and noticed I never accepted your answer.  I've done so now, sorry for the delay!